# Mega and Ubuntu 22.04 unable to install

Tags: nautilus, mega

at first, I go through any possible answer for this problem, nothing seems to work.

1. I've download Mega https://mega.nz/desktop (22.06, Nautilus)
2. Try to install it using software center, I have:

[Unable to install nautilus-megasync: The following packages have unmett dependencies:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgfIO.png)

3. Try same using terminal by:

   **sudo dpkg -i nautilus-megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb**

GIVES ME

```
Selecting previously unselected package nautilus-megasync.
(Reading database ... 195292 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack nautilus-megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nautilus-megasync (3.6.6) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nautilus-megasync:
 nautilus-megasync depends on megasync; however:
  Package megasync is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nautilus-megasync (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
```

ALSO TRY:

**apt install libcrypto++8 libc-ares2 libmediainfo0v5 libssl3**

```
Selecting previously unselected package nautilus-megasync.
(Reading database ... 195292 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack nautilus-megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nautilus-megasync (3.6.6) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nautilus-megasync:
 nautilus-megasync depends on megasync; however:
  Package megasync is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nautilus-megasync (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
```

FINALLY what I've:

**sudo apt install mega.deb**

```
sudo dpkg -i mega.deb
(Reading database ... 211558 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mega.deb ...
Unpacking nautilus-megasync (3.6.6) over (3.6.6) ...
Please restart all running instances of Nautilus.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nautilus-megasync:
 nautilus-megasync depends on megasync; however:
  Package megasync is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nautilus-megasync (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: `nautilus-megasync depends on megasync; however:
  Package megasync is not installed.`

Answer (score 1):

Install `megasync` first. You can download it from the same site.

[image]

You'll get `megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb`

Install it by `sudo apt install ./megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb`

After that you should be able to install the Nautilus extension.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I can't find it, I was looking for it before I ask question. At this site https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_22.04/ 

there is only nautilus-megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb

Comment: https://mega.nz/desktop you can select a version and download `megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb`

Comment: no, I can't. At my first post I've post this link. I am downloading .deb from this link for the beginning, and the file is: nautilus-megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb it is file for MEGA app...

Comment: There are two download links.

Comment: holly c... You are right! Thanks for save my sanity ;)

IMHO this is so bad designed. I was on this site so many times, do not have idea to download two files.

Simply adding 1. and 2. on this boxes...

Should find out that something is wrong on my side because there was no answer for my doubts.

Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

run terminal in the download directory and enter root `su` or use sudo

Then type:

```
dpkg -i megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb
```

Resilve the error with `apt-get -f install`

run `sudo dpkg -i megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb`

Now install the extension

```
dpkg -i nautilus-megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb
```

Finaly run  `megasync` to open it

if it doen't open run `apt update` then `apt upgrade` and `apt --fix-broken install`  then pre 'y' to accept installation